# How will RingCT interact with view keys?

Tags: ringct, viewkey

Can view keys reveal the amount of a transaction? Will they be able to view outgoing as well as ingoing transactions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

View keys will be able to reveal the amount of an incoming transaction, as currently. They will not be able to view outgoing transactions, as currently. Basically, nothing changes on that front.

Answer (score 0):

The cryptography behind how the view key works will change slightly, but the functionality of a view key will remain the same. You will be able to see the incoming transactions, but you will not be able to see outgoing transactions.